flinkcdc 2.4 snapshot.select.statement.overrides how to config
I need use flinkcdc 2.4 capture data from mysql , I need write a backfill program, I want to do a initial mode just capture the subset of the table, I find the property snapshot.select.statement.overrides, but it does not work, I find a issue in github
https://github.com/apache/flink-cdc/discussions/1131
it said the scan.incremental.snapshot.enabled should be false, but how to config this property to false in datastream api? thanks


 String  dbName="db1";
          String  tableName="table11";
          String query = "select * from db1.table11 where id='1' ";

            Properties debeziumProperties = new Properties();

//            debeziumProperties.put("scan.incremental.snapshot.enabled", "false");
//            debeziumProperties.put("snapshot.select.statement.overrides",String.format("%s.%s",dbName,tableName));
//            debeziumProperties.put(String.format("snapshot.select.statement.overrides.%s.%s", dbName,tableName), query);

            debeziumProperties.put("snapshot.select.statement.overrides","db1.table11");
            debeziumProperties.put("snapshot.select.statement.overrides.db1.table11", query);

            String configFile =  "application-batch.conf";
            ConfigParser.init(configFile);
            ConfigParser.MySqlConfig config = ConfigParser.getMysqlConfig();
            Map<String, Object> jsonConvertConfig = new HashMap<>();
            jsonConvertConfig.put(JsonConverterConfig.DECIMAL_FORMAT_CONFIG, DecimalFormat.NUMERIC.name());



            MySqlSourceBuilder<String> builder = MySqlSource.<String>builder()
                    .hostname(config.getHost())
                    .port(config.getPort())
                    .databaseList(dbName)
                    .tableList(String.format("%s.%s",dbName,tableName))
                    .username(config.getUserName())
                    .password(config.getPassword())
                    .debeziumProperties(debeziumProperties)
                    .deserializer(new JsonDebeziumDeserializationSchema(true, jsonConvertConfig))
                    .startupOptions(StartupOptions.initial());



Many thanks.
